# Zoom on userLocation

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

how can I zoom the map on my userLocation automatically in my app?
I have the following code to zomm in the map but i must zoom on the userLocation and the following code zooms always to africa?

```
MKCoordinateRegion zoomIn = mapView.region;
    zoomIn.span.latitudeDelta *= 0.2;
    zoomIn.span.longitudeDelta *= 0.2;
    zoomIn.center.latitude = mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude;
    zoomIn.center.longitude = mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude;
    [mapView setRegion:zoomIn animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK i solved the problem, with the following delegate Method:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views{
    for(MKAnnotationView *annotationView in views) {
        if(annotationView.annotation == mv.userLocation){
            MKCoordinateRegion region;
            MKCoordinateSpan span;

            span.latitudeDelta=0.9;
            span.longitudeDelta=0.9;

            CLLocationCoordinate2D location =mv.userLocation.coordinate;

            location = mv.userLocation.location.coordinate;

            region.span = span;
            region.center = location;
            [mv setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
            [mv regionThatFits:region];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

thanks alot mate, this helped me greatly. Really wanted to vote but cant because of my rep level.

I also found that using:

```
mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude;
```

always zoomed me to africa, and never centered me onto my current location.

But by using the delegate method:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)myMapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {
```

I was able to solve this successfully. What I discovered is that when using mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude; in the viewDidLoad method wasn't triggering the correct user coords on startup of the view, hence it was displaying the wrong coords.

Comment: for the benefit of newcomers: sometimes when it is working properly it may still go the Atlantic off the african coast because you are running it in the simulator, and Location ( under Debug ) is set to None